# Python -Remove capitalized words from long string

Tags: python, string

I have long string (28MB) of normal sentences. I want to remove all words what are fully in capital letters (like TNT, USA, OMG).

So from sentance:

```
Jump over TNT in There.
```

I would like to get:

```
Jump over  in There.
```

Is there any way, how to do it without splitting the text into list and itereate? Is it possible to use regex somehow to do is?

Comment: Why dont you want to split the string?

Comment: @jmetz I have not tried anything, because the solution I know is sub-optimal (and trivial). I saw the documentation of `re`, but it is complicated for me - I always struggle to find out how to achieve what I want.

Comment: @TinoA. In my experience when I split long string and iterate over it, it takes more time than usage of `re` (but maybe I am wrong)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the set of capital letters `[A-Z]` captured with word boundary `\b`:

```
import re

line = 'Jump over TNT in There NOW'

m = re.sub(r'\b[A-Z]+\b', '', line)
#'Jump over  in There '
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the module [**`re`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html),

```
import re

line = 'Jump over TNT in There.'
new_line = re.sub(r'[A-Z]+(?![a-z])', '', line)

print(new_line)
# Output
Jump over  in There.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
import string

def onlyUpper(word):
    for c in word:
        if not c.isupper():
            return False
    return True

s = "Jump over TNT in There."
for char in string.punctuation:
    s = s.replace(char, ' ')

words = s.split()
good_words = []

for w in words:
    if not onlyUpper(w):
        good_words.append(w)

result = ""
for w in good_words:
    result = result + w + " "

print result
```